# Python OpenCV code to Java

Tags: java, python, opencv

I am familiar with using Python and OpenCV. However, as I need to run my code on an android phone, I need to re-write my code in Java. Is there any other way to go about this? Is there any documentation on how to migrate from Python OpenCV to Java?

Comment: Yes. The logic is agnostic to whatever language you're using. OpenCV is an interface to the same set of CV tools. If the opencv function exists in python, then an equivalent exists in java.